# Sharepoint 2013 Site Returns 304 Not Modified

Tags: sharepoint, robots.txt, google-crawlers

One of the sharepoint 2013 site is not able to crawled by google bot. Google said, he is not able to reach Robots.txt. 
When i look from chrome developer tools, it seems server return 304 code.

How can i solve this problem?

EDIT: 
When i call the url without "www."(xxxxx.com/robots.txt) , server returning 200 ok.

User-agent: *

```
Allow: /

Disallow: /_layouts/
Disallow: /_vti_bin/
Disallow: /_catalogs/


Sitemap: http://www.xxxxxxx.com:80/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: This question is better suited for http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com. You should check alternate access mappings to make sure `www.` is known to SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

Need to give access to crawler service on firewall.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /_layouts/
Disallow: /_vti_bin/
Disallow: /_catalogs/
Sitemap: sitemap.xml
```